# PNG Filereader Implementation in C++: Using libpng

Tags: c++

This is a general poste about what I can improve in my coding style while wrapping C libraries up into C++.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <png.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class PNGFileReader
{
  public:
    PNGFileReader();
    ~PNGFileReader();
    // Public exposed API:
    bool compress_raw_to_png(uint8_t data, int size);
    bool decompress_png_to_raw(const std::string &path);

    // Getters
    long unsigned int get_image_width();
    long unsigned int get_image_height();
    void get_image_data(std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char> > &data);

  private:
    // Helper functions:
    bool read_png(const std::string &path);
    bool create_png_structs(FILE *fp);
    bool free_data();
    bool alloc_data();

    // Member variables:
    png_structp m_pPNG;
    png_infop m_pPNGInfo;
    png_infop m_pPNGEndInfo;
    png_bytepp m_Data;
    long unsigned int m_ImageWidth;
    long unsigned int m_ImageHeight;

    // Enums
    enum PNGBOOL {NOT_PNG, PNG};
    enum PNGERRORS {ERROR, SUCCESS};
};

#endif /* PNG_FILE_READER_H_ */
```

---

```
#include "pngfilereader.h"
#include <stdexcept>

PNGFileReader::PNGFileReader() :
  m_pPNG(NULL),
  m_pPNGInfo(NULL),
  m_pPNGEndInfo(NULL),
  m_Data(NULL),
  m_ImageWidth(0),
  m_ImageHeight(0)
{
}

PNGFileReader::~PNGFileReader()
{
  for (unsigned long int i = 0; i < m_ImageHeight; ++i) {
    if (m_Data[i]) {
      delete m_Data[i];
      m_Data[i] = NULL;
    }   
  }
  if (m_Data) {
    delete m_Data;
    m_Data = NULL;
  }
}

// Public Exposed API
bool PNGFileReader::compress_raw_to_png(uint8_t m_Data, int size)
{
  return PNGFileReader::SUCCESS;
}

bool PNGFileReader::decompress_png_to_raw(const std::string &path)
{
  return read_png(path);
}

// Getters
long unsigned int PNGFileReader::get_image_width()
{
  return m_ImageWidth;
}

long unsigned int PNGFileReader::get_image_height()
{
  return m_ImageHeight;
}

void PNGFileReader::get_image_data(
  std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char> > &data)
{
  for (unsigned long int i = 0; i < m_ImageHeight; ++i) {
    std::vector<unsigned char> v;
    data.push_back(v);
    for (unsigned long int j = 0; j < m_ImageWidth; ++j) {
      std::vector<unsigned char> *vp = &data[i];
      vp->push_back(m_Data[i][j]);
    } 
  }
}

// Private Methods
bool PNGFileReader::read_png(const std::string &path)
{
  /* 
   * Open up the file to read (path) in binary mode
   * first so that if anything goes wrong with libpng
   * we won't have much to undo
   */
  const char *c_path = path.c_str();
  FILE *fp = fopen(c_path, "rb");
  if (!fp)
    return PNGFileReader::ERROR;

  /*
   * Read the first BYTES_TO_READ bytes from file
   * then determine if it is a png file or 
   * not. If png_sig_cmp == 0 all is okay
   */
  enum {BYTES_TO_READ = 8};
  unsigned char sig[BYTES_TO_READ];
  if (!fread(sig, 1, BYTES_TO_READ, fp)) {
    fclose(fp);
    return PNGFileReader::ERROR;
  }

  bool is_png = !png_sig_cmp(sig, 0, BYTES_TO_READ);
  if (!is_png) {
    fclose(fp);
    return PNGFileReader::ERROR;   
  }

  if (!this->create_png_structs(fp)) {
    fclose(fp);
    return PNGFileReader::ERROR;
  }

  /*
   * For error handling purposes. Set a long pointer
   * back to this function to handle all error related
   * to file IO
   */
  if (setjmp(png_jmpbuf(m_pPNG)))
  {
    png_destroy_read_struct(&m_pPNG, &m_pPNGInfo, &m_pPNGEndInfo);
    fclose(fp);
    return PNGFileReader::ERROR;
  }

  /* 
   * Set up the input code for FILE openend in binary mode,
   * and tell libpng we have already read BYTES_TO_READ btyes from 
   * signature
   */
  png_init_io(m_pPNG, fp);
  png_set_sig_bytes(m_pPNG, BYTES_TO_READ);

  /*
   * Using the lowlevel interface to lib png ...
   */
  png_read_info(m_pPNG, m_pPNGInfo);
  m_ImageHeight = png_get_image_height(m_pPNG, m_pPNGInfo);
  m_ImageWidth = png_get_rowbytes(m_pPNG, m_pPNGInfo);
  this->alloc_data();
  png_read_image(m_pPNG, m_Data);

  png_read_end(m_pPNG, NULL);
  png_destroy_read_struct(&m_pPNG, &m_pPNGInfo, &m_pPNGEndInfo);
  fclose(fp);

  return PNGFileReader::SUCCESS;
}

bool PNGFileReader::create_png_structs(FILE *fp)
{
  /* 
   * Create the pointer to main libpng struct, as well as
   * two info structs to maintain information after, and
   * prior to all operations on png m_Data. Only necessary
   * to release resource after function succeeds.
   */
  m_pPNG = png_create_read_struct(PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING, (png_voidp)NULL,
    NULL, NULL);
  if (!m_pPNG)
  {
    fclose(fp);
    return PNGFileReader::ERROR;
  }
  m_pPNGInfo = png_create_info_struct(m_pPNG);
  if (!m_pPNGInfo)
  {
    png_destroy_read_struct(&m_pPNG, (png_infopp)NULL,(png_infopp)NULL);
    fclose(fp);
    return PNGFileReader::ERROR;
  }
  m_pPNGEndInfo = png_create_info_struct(m_pPNG);
  if (!m_pPNGEndInfo)
  {
    png_destroy_read_struct(&m_pPNG, &m_pPNGInfo, (png_infopp)NULL);
    fclose(fp);
    return PNGFileReader::ERROR;
  }
  return PNGFileReader::SUCCESS;
}

bool PNGFileReader::free_data()
{
  if (m_ImageHeight == 0 || m_ImageWidth == 0)
    return PNGFileReader::ERROR;

  for (unsigned long int i = 0; i < m_ImageHeight; ++i) {
    if (m_Data[i]) {
      delete m_Data[i];
      m_Data[i] = NULL;
    }
  }
  if (m_Data) {
    delete m_Data;
    m_Data = NULL;
  }
  return PNGFileReader::SUCCESS;
}

bool PNGFileReader::alloc_data()
{
  if (m_ImageHeight == 0 || m_ImageWidth == 0)
    return PNGFileReader::ERROR;

  if (m_Data != NULL)
    this->free_data();

  m_Data = new png_bytep[m_ImageHeight]();           
  for (unsigned long int i = 0; i < m_ImageHeight; ++i) {
    m_Data[i] = NULL;
  }
  try {
    for (unsigned long int i = 0; i < m_ImageHeight; ++i) {
      m_Data[i] = new png_byte[m_ImageWidth];
    }
  }
  catch (std::bad_alloc e) {
    for (unsigned long int i = 0; i < m_ImageHeight; ++i) {
      if (m_Data[i]) {
        delete m_Data[i];
        m_Data[i] = NULL;
      }
    }
    if (m_Data) {
      delete m_Data;
      m_Data = NULL;
    }
    throw e;
  }

  return PNGFileReader::SUCCESS;
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

In trying to take all your points into consideration, I have rewritten the program, and have attempted to use RAII as much as possible. Please let me know if I am not using RAII correctly, or if there are other things that I need to improve upon.

```
#include "pngfilereader.h"
#include <iostream>

int main (int /*argc*/, char **/*argv*/)
{
  PNGFileReader pngfr("/home/matt6809/Downloads/info-32x32.png");
  std::cout << &pngfr;
  return 0;
}
```

---

```
#ifndef PNG_FILE_READER_H_
#define PNG_FILE_READER_H_

#include "imagedata.h"
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <png.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

template <typename data_type>
class ImageData;

class PNGFileReader
{
  public:
    // Ctor and Dtor
    PNGFileReader(const std::string &path);
    ~PNGFileReader();

    // For testing purposes
    friend std::ostream &operator<< (std::ostream &out, 
      PNGFileReader *object)
    {
      for (unsigned long i = 0; i < object->get_image_height(); ++i) {
        for (unsigned long j = 0; j < object->get_image_width(); ++j) {
          out << object->_m_Image->get_data()[i][j];
        }   
      }
      return out;
    }

    // Getters
    long unsigned int get_image_width();
    long unsigned int get_image_height();

  private:
    // Helper functions:
    bool _create_png_structs();

    // Member variables:
    FILE *_m_CFilePointer;
    ImageData<unsigned char> *_m_Image;
    png_structp _m_pPNG;
    png_infop _m_pPNGInfo;
    long unsigned int _m_ImageWidth;
    long unsigned int _m_ImageHeight;

    // Enums
    enum PNGBOOL {NOT_PNG, PNG};
    enum PNGERRORS {ERROR, SUCCESS};
};

#endif /* PNG_FILE_READER_H_ */
```

---

```
#include "pngfilereader.h"
#include "filereader.h"
#include "imagedata.h"
#include <stdexcept>


PNGFileReader::PNGFileReader(const std::string &path) :
  _m_pPNG(NULL),
  _m_pPNGInfo(NULL),
  _m_ImageWidth(0),
  _m_ImageHeight(0)
{
  /*
   * Check if first 8 bytes are the correct PNG header
   */ 
  enum {BYTES_TO_READ = 8};
  unsigned char sig[BYTES_TO_READ];
  FileReader(path, sig, BYTES_TO_READ);
  bool not_png = png_sig_cmp(sig, 0, BYTES_TO_READ);
  if (not_png) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Your file is not of PNG format");
  }

  /*
   * Create the png structs using a FILE *. libpng requires
   * this type and will not take a C++ stream
   */ 
  _m_CFilePointer = fopen(path.c_str(), "rb");
  if (!_m_CFilePointer) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Failure to open PNG file");
  }
  if (!_create_png_structs()) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Failure to create PNG structs");   
  }

  /*
   * Initialize PNG io and read data into PNG structs
   */ 
  png_init_io(_m_pPNG, _m_CFilePointer);
  png_read_info(_m_pPNG, _m_pPNGInfo);
  _m_ImageHeight = png_get_image_height(_m_pPNG, _m_pPNGInfo);
  _m_ImageWidth = png_get_rowbytes(_m_pPNG, _m_pPNGInfo);

  /*
   * Read Image in all at once into users data
   */  
  _m_Image = new ImageData<unsigned char>(_m_ImageWidth, _m_ImageHeight);
  png_read_image(_m_pPNG, _m_Image->get_data());
  png_read_end(_m_pPNG, NULL);
  fclose(_m_CFilePointer);
  _m_CFilePointer = NULL;
}

PNGFileReader::~PNGFileReader()
{
  if (_m_CFilePointer) {
    fclose(_m_CFilePointer);
  }
  png_destroy_read_struct(&_m_pPNG, &_m_pPNGInfo, NULL);
  delete _m_Image;
}

// Getters
long unsigned int PNGFileReader::get_image_width()
{
  return _m_ImageWidth;
}

long unsigned int PNGFileReader::get_image_height()
{
  return _m_ImageHeight;
}

// Private helper functions
bool PNGFileReader::_create_png_structs()
{
  /* 
   * Create the pointer to main libpng struct, as well as
   * two info structs to maintain information after, and
   * prior to all operations on png m_Data. Only necessary
   * to release resource after function succeeds.
   */
  _m_pPNG = png_create_read_struct(PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING, (png_voidp)NULL,
    NULL, NULL);
  if (!_m_pPNG){
    return PNGFileReader::ERROR;
  }

  _m_pPNGInfo = png_create_info_struct(_m_pPNG);
  if (!_m_pPNGInfo) {
    return PNGFileReader::ERROR;
  }

  return PNGFileReader::SUCCESS;
}
```

---

```
#ifndef IMAGE_DATA_
#define IMAGE_DATA_

 #include <stdexcept>

template <typename data_type>
class ImageData 
{
public:
  ImageData(unsigned long width, unsigned long height);
  ~ImageData();
  ImageData(ImageData &copy);
  ImageData& operator= (ImageData &copy);
  data_type **&get_data();
private:
  data_type **_m_rData;
  unsigned long _m_Width;
  unsigned long _m_Height;
};

template <typename data_type>
ImageData<data_type>::ImageData(unsigned long width, unsigned long height) :
  _m_rData(NULL),
  _m_Width(width),
  _m_Height(height)
{
  if (width == 0 || height == 0)
    throw std::runtime_error("Invalid width or height");

  try {
    _m_rData = new data_type*[height]();
    for (unsigned long int i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
      _m_rData[i] = NULL;
    }
    for (unsigned long int i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
      _m_rData[i] = new data_type[width];
    }
  }
  catch (std::bad_alloc e) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Failure to create space for Image");
  }
}

template <typename data_type>
ImageData<data_type>::~ImageData()
{
  for (unsigned long i = 0; i < _m_Height; ++i) {
    delete [] _m_rData[i];
    _m_rData[i] = NULL;
  }
  delete _m_rData;
  _m_rData = NULL;
}

template <typename data_type>
ImageData<data_type>::ImageData(ImageData &copy)
{
}

template <typename data_type>
ImageData<data_type>& ImageData<data_type>::operator= (ImageData &copy)
{
}

template <typename data_type>
data_type **&ImageData<data_type>::get_data()
{
  return _m_rData;
}

#endif
```

---

```
#ifndef FILEREADER_H_
#define FILEREADER_H_

#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

class FileReader
{
public:
  FileReader(const std::string &path, unsigned char data[], 
    long long bytes_to_read);
  ~FileReader();
private:
  std::ifstream _m_InFile;
};

#endif
```

---

```
#include "filereader.h"
#include <stdexcept>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

FileReader::FileReader(const std::string &path, 
  unsigned char data[], long long bytes_to_read)
{
  _m_InFile.open(path.c_str());
  if (!_m_InFile) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Failure to open " + path);
  }

  try {
    _m_InFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(data), bytes_to_read);
  } catch (std::ios_base::failure e) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Failure while reading first N bytes");
  }
}

FileReader::~FileReader()
{
  _m_InFile.close();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Style Comments:

- No need to check if a pointer is NULL before deleting:
- Since you use `new X[size];` to allocate the memory you should delete with `delete [] data;`
- I see multiple copies of the freeing loop so put it in one place and call the free method everywhere you use it:

Free:

```
  for (unsigned long int i = 0; i < m_ImageHeight; ++i) 
  {
    if (m_Data[i]) {
      delete m_Data[i];
      m_Data[i] = NULL;
    }   
  }
  if (m_Data) {
    delete m_Data;
    m_Data = NULL;
  }
```

Should be:

```
  for (unsigned long int i = 0; i < m_ImageHeight; ++i) 
  {
      delete [] m_Data[i];
  }   
  delete m_Data;
  m_Data = NULL;
```

Personally I would take this a step further and encapsulate m_Data into its own class that understands how to handle the memory then just call clear() on the new class to empty it (destructor automatically calls clear).

Your get function seems very ineffecient?

```
void PNGFileReader::get_image_data(
  std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char> > &data)
{
  for (unsigned long int i = 0; i < m_ImageHeight; ++i) {
    std::vector<unsigned char> v;
    data.push_back(v);
    for (unsigned long int j = 0; j < m_ImageWidth; ++j) {
      std::vector<unsigned char> *vp = &data[i];
      vp->push_back(m_Data[i][j]);
    } 
  }
}
```

You are making a copy of all the data to send back to the user. This brings me back the class for encapsulating the raw data (m_data above). If you had encapsulated that data in a class you could just return a const reference to this internal object, thus no copying required.

Also I don't particularly like the lines:

```
      std::vector<unsigned char> *vp = &data[i];
      vp->push_back(m_Data[i][j]);
```

Personally I think it is much easier to read as:

```
      data[i].push_back(m_Data[i][j]);
```

If you must have an indirection I would have used a reference not a pointer:

```
      std::vector<unsigned char>&  vp = data[i];
      vp.push_back(m_Data[i][j]);
```

Reading from a file:

```
if (!fread(sig, 1, BYTES_TO_READ, fp))
```

Unfortunately this can still fail (and your code will not notice). You need to check the amount read is the amount requeted:

```
if (fread(sig, 1, BYTES_TO_READ, fp) == BYTES_TO_READ)
```

Alternatively you can set the number of objects to one then the not test will work as you expect:

```
if (!fread(sig, BYTES_TO_READ, 1, fp))
 ///            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^      Notice the size comes first
 //                           ^^   We only want one so the result is 0 or 1
```

OK there is something wrong when you start setting long jumps:

```
if (setjmp(png_jmpbuf(m_pPNG)))
```

This implies you have not set your object up correctly. Some exceptions should help you cover this in a much more readable and maintainable fashion.

All over the code you are repeating the same error handling:

```
   fclose(fp);
   return errorCode.
```

The manual close indicates that you should be wrapping the file pointer in some RAII structure so that it can not be accidentally be left open. Currently your code is becoming a maintenance nightmare as any new developer will have to remember to close resources manually (when things have to be done manually this is a bad design as it will cost in maintenance bugs)

#### Overall structure.

I don't like the two phase creation.

```
PNGFileReader    png1;
png1.compress_raw_to_png(data, data.size());

// or

PNGFileReader    png2;
png2.decompress_png_to_raw("Plop.png");
```

What I would rather see is an object that is full constructed:

```
PNGFileReader    png1("File");
PNGFileReader    png2(vectorOfRawData);
```

Then you can perform actions on the objects.

Comment: Thanks again for the input, I have made the respective changes, could you please take one last look at my updates to let me know if I have made them correctly?

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is better to make separate `Image` class and convert `PNGFileReader` into a factory/builder for the `Image`. It will completely change the code, but you see that it will force you to have clearer code.

At least, it is better to use streams instead of `FILE` and get rid of all "if the file is ok" checks.

Regarding style, I think that naming convention could be better, like use distinctive names for private methods (`_read_png`, for example). Constructor (as it is implemented) can be inlined.

I prefer to use `{}` even if there is just one line after `if`, or `while` - it will produce more readable code, plus it will decrease number of differences if you use a version control system.

Pieces like

```
bool is_png = !png_sig_cmp(sig, 0, BYTES_TO_READ);
if (!is_png) { .....
```

are really hard to understand (double negation is always a good brain killer).

Use more `try catch` around memory allocations and low level IO operations.

Code like

```
if (m_Data != NULL)
    this->free_data();

m_Data = new png_bytep[m_ImageHeight]();
```

is not exception save. It is better to follow another pattern like 1) allocate memory 2) copy old data to new / do operations 3) free old data. In this way you will have old data at least, not an object in half-desintegrated state.

Since you have a lot of cleanup code (`delete` and `fclose`) it creates good bug opportunities. You may consider "RAII" (Resource Acquisition In Initialization) pattern: make an object that will create in ctor and hold all temporary resources, and clean up them in dtor. Then, declare that object as a variable in local sope - so it will create resources upon scope entry. When it leaves the scope (exception or return statement at any line of the code) its destructor will clean up resources consistently.

**EDIT after author's update**

Perhaps, `PNGFileReader` should be a template too and have a getter for `Image`. Anyway, this getter is missing, right? If it had this one, it would not have `get_image_width()` - the `Image` knww it's dimensions better.

Anyway, if you need getters mark them as constant (and inline in simple cases):

```
inline long unsigned int PNGFileReader::get_image_width() const
```

It will give more room for optimization for a compiler.

"Create the png structs using a FILE *. libpng requires this type and will not take a C++ stream" - good point. I did not know that. You should drop `FileReader` then, no point to have it.

```
for (unsigned long int i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
  _m_rData[i] = NULL;
}
```

`memset` works better...

```
data_type **&get_data();
```

Do you *really* understand what does it mean? I do not and I believe such clever things must be avoided at any cost. well, if you want to compete with C++ standardization commetee and compiler developers....

It is better to overload `[]` (or `()`) operators to give users access to the image.

Copy constructor and assignment operator should be `ImageData(const ImageData &copy)` and `operator= (const ImageData &copy)`, if you want disable them (and this may be a good idea) do not use any implementation at all. Use just declaration (mandatory, otherwise compiler will generate copy constructor for you), it will allow to have compile-time errors on copy/assignmnet attemts. Like now, compiler will eat it, so programm will work in unplanned way (somebody write `image1 = image2`, compiles says "ok", but image1 is empty at run-time).

Underscore as prefix to members is a bit overkill, good class should not have public members anyway, right? So, `m_something` is a good style already.

Comment: Thanks again for the input, I have made the respective changes, could you please take one last look at my updates to let me know if I have made them correctly?